# How do I ensure GetDC() always works on background windows?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, gdi

I have a script in AHK which uses a function PixelColorSimple.

```
PixelColorSimple(pc_x, pc_y, pc_wID) {
    if pc_wID
    {
    pc_hDC := DllCall("GetDC", "UInt", pc_wID)
    pc_fmtI := A_FormatInteger
    SetFormat, IntegerFast, Hex
    pc_c := DllCall("GetPixel", "UInt", pc_hDC, "Int", pc_x, "Int", pc_y, "UInt")
    pc_c := pc_c >> 16 & 0xff | pc_c & 0xff00 | (pc_c & 0xff) << 16
    pc_c .= ""
    SetFormat, IntegerFast, %pc_fmtI%
    DllCall("ReleaseDC", "UInt", pc_wID, "UInt", pc_hDC)
    return pc_c
    }
}
```

It retrieves a pixel's color from a background/foreground non-minimized window even if the pixel is behind another window. I need my script to run on a background window while I work on another window that's in front of it. It works perfectly until about 6 to 10 minutes later when it gets stuck in a loop with this function and I'll have to bring the window to the foreground for it to resume working as it should. I'm thinking my computer disallows `GetDC()` from working on background windows after a period of time, so any ideas on how I can ensure it doesn't do that? Or is the problem here not with `GetDC()`? Thank you.

Comment: `CS_OWNDC` may be

Comment: Could also be `CS_CLASSDC`. Also check for the return of `ReleaseDC`. How's the entire function called? It's possible `pc_wID` has gone out of scope.